# Text node background behavior when wrapping

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems with a behavior I have never seen before. I added the code because Stack Overflow is asking me to put it in my post but I would recommend you go on [the Codepen](https://codepen.io/Thegreen0ne/pen/QWNYyvw?editors=1100) to try it for yourself.

HTML:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="name">Testing and Testeronintendo</div>
      <div class="star">X</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  background: green;
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
}

.card {
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.name {
  background: red;
}
```

Here is an image with a hand drawn example of the behavior I expect/need: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tWRH.png

Explanation: I don't want the red background to extend all the way to the X, I simply want it to wrap cleanly around the text of the div.

Comment: Wrap your text in a `span` and do a background on that. `.name` div background will show as per its size.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work, I already tried it before. Thanks for the comment though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the minimum content of width to your name class. As far as I know by reading your question I understand that you want to make the red background as it's needed.

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  background: green;
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
}

.card {
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.name {
  background: red;
  width: min-content;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="name">Testing and Testeronintendo</div>
      <div class="star">X</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amazing, it works. I really didn't know about width: min-content. I guess we learn something new everyday. Thanks a lot!